# Does the rate of change of entropy vary in time

Tags: thermodynamics, structure-formation

John wheeler once jokingly  said he was feeling uneasy putting a hot cup next to a cold cup as he'd be contributing to the entropy of the universe or at least accelerating it.

Then again the very nature of time itself seems to be dependent on entropy and not the other way around.?

Can some process slow donwn the inevitable time decay of "order" in the universe, and are our galaxy and other galaxies with more and more newly discovered(electromagnetic and otherwise) structure examples of a  seemingly physically  unlikely structured system standing the test of time and the long overdue dissolution by the second law?